# syntax error with $

Tags: math-mode, errors, syntax

```
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |p{4cm}|p{8cm}|}
 \hline
 Model& Branching Fractions \\
 \hline
 \widetilde{B}-\widetilde{t}\ \text{coannihilation}& 79\% $\tau{^{-}}\tau{^{+}}$,\ 15\% $b\overline{b}$, \ 5\% $\textit{g}\textit{g}$ \\
 Pure \widetilde{h}& 50\%\ W{^{-}} W{^{+}}, 41\%\ ZZ, 6\% \ $W{^{\pm}}H{^{\mp}}$, 1\% \ \textit{h}Z\\
 \widetilde{B}-\widetilde{q}\ \text{coannihilation}& 69\% $\textit{g}\textit{g}$, 29\% $b\overline{b}$ \\
 A funnel& 72\% $b\overline{b}$, 18\% $t\overline{t}$, 10\%$\tau{^{-}}\tau{^{+}}$ \\
 Well-tempered \widetilde{\chi}& 53\% \ $W{^{-}} W{^{+}}$, 37\%\ ZZ, 5\% \ $\textit{h}Z$, 4\% \ $b\overline{b}$\\

 \hline
\end{tabular}
```

All but one line(A funnel line is correct) is saying I'm missing a $, but I'm unable to find where. I'm sure it's something simple, and I'm overthinking the syntax

Comment: For example, in the cell under Model (line 6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input is quite inconsistent. However, the main problem is in that you're not confining math mode material inside math mode.

For instance, you have

```
$\tau{^{-}}\tau{^{+}}$
```

but start the first cell in the second row with

```
\widetilde{B}-\widetilde{t}\ \text{coannihilation}
```

This should be instead

```
$\widetilde{B}-\widetilde{t}$ coannihilation
```

Also the spacing you use is inconsistent.

By the way, also `\tau{^{-}}` is incorrect and should be `\tau^{-}`; the same for the other similar situations.

Here's an edited version of the table, where `\addlinespace` has been used because of the high parts introduced by the tildes.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} l l @{} }
\toprule
Model & Branching Fractions \\
\midrule
$\widetilde{B}-\widetilde{t}$ coannihilation &
  79\% $\tau^{-}\tau^{+}$,\ 15\% $b\bar{b}$, 5\% $gg$ \\
\addlinespace
Pure $\widetilde{h}$ &
  50\%\ $W^{-}W^{+}$, 41\% $ZZ$, 6\% $W^{\pm}H^{\mp}$, 1\% $hZ$ \\
\addlinespace
$\widetilde{B}-\widetilde{q}$ coannihilation &
  69\% $gg$, 29\% $b\bar{b}$ \\
\addlinespace
A funnel &
  72\% $b\bar{b}$, 18\% $t\bar{t}$, 10\% $\tau^{-}\tau^{+}$ \\
\addlinespace
Well-tempered $\widetilde{\chi}$ &
  53\% $W^{-}W^{+}$, 37\%\ $ZZ$, 5\% $hZ$, 4\% $b\bar{b}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the W's and Z's have to be upright, use `\mathrm{W}` and `\mathrm{Z}`.

Answer (score 3):

We can learn what TeX is saying during error messages. These messages tell you where is the problem. I run your code and I see following TeX messages:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.10  \widetilde
                {B}-\widetilde{t}\ \text{coannihilation}& 79\% $\tau{^{-}}\t...

?
```

The important part of the message is the part where the line of your code is broken to two lines, at the end of the first line. It is `\widetitle` here. TeX says that `\widetitle` cannot be used in text mode, but only in math mode. It suggests to add `$` before `\widetitle` to recover this error. We can enter Enter (it means that we accept such recovering) and TeX continues. We see next error message:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.10 ...e{B}-\widetilde{t}\ \text{coannihilation}&
                                                   79\% $\tau{^{-}}\tau{^{+}...

?
```

The important place is `&` now (here the line is broken to two lines). TeX says that you cannot close one table cell without closing the math mode. Yes, this mode was started as a part of recovering the previous error. TeX suggests to insert `$` in order to close the math mode. If we enter Enter then we accept such recovering. Next error message is:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.11  Pure \widetilde
                     {h}& 50\%\ W{^{-}} W{^{+}}, 41\%\ ZZ, 6\% \ $W{^{\pm}}H...

?
```

This is similar to first. Next error message is:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.11  Pure \widetilde{h}&
                          50\%\ W{^{-}} W{^{+}}, 41\%\ ZZ, 6\% \ $W{^{\pm}}H...

?
```

This is similar to second. Next error message is:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.11  Pure \widetilde{h}& 50\%\ W{^
                                   {-}} W{^{+}}, 41\%\ ZZ, 6\% \ $W{^{\pm}}H...

?
```

TeX says that you cannot use `^` outside math mode and suggests to insert `$` right before this character. If we enter Enter then `W{$^{-}}` is processed and this is the reason of next error message:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
l.11  Pure \widetilde{h}& 50\%\ W{^{-}}
                                        W{^{+}}, 41\%\ ZZ, 6\% \ $W{^{\pm}}H...

?
```

TeX says that you cannot close a group by `}` because the group was opened by `$`, note: `W$^{-}}`. It suggests to recover this by `W{$^{-}$}`. Next error messages are similar to messages mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

`W{^{+}}` is incorrect because the `^{+}` is isolated from the `W` (this happens several times).  You may mean `$W^{+}$`.  Notice also that it has to occur within `$`.

Comment: Well yes, but that doesn't fix all the missing $ errors ..